# Data download from server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I want to download multiple files (file is in zip format) from server to client machine specific path within unzip format. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does `Specific path within unzip format` mean?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that these constituent files of the archive are meant to present in a particular path in the archive? If not, please answer The Elite Gentleman's query.

Comment: @The Elite: I *guess* that he want to have full control over unzipping at the client machine.

Comment: not sure what any of the current tags java/jsp/tomcat have to do with this

Answer (score 0):

If the server exposes these files as an HTTP resource, any HTTP client program (such as [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/), browsers and others) would be able to retrieve them.  If the resources are exposed in another fashion, you'll need to use an appropriate client for that (e.g. SMB shares you can mount the resource using Explorer or [SAMBA](http://www.samba.org/); FTP you can use an FTP client; etc.).

To download multiple files, unless you're talking about thousands, you can simply invoke the client once for each file.  If you want this to be done programatically (e.g. as part of a build), this can be done with a shell script (batch script in windows) or as part of some higher-level construct, e.g. an Ant script if it's part of a Java-based project's build.

If your problem is that the server isn't currently making the files available, you'll need to make your question more specific to clarify this.

Comment: I want to download multiple files in single response (files is in zip format) from server to client machine within unzip format. How can I achieve this? Language:JSP  Please help me.....